# Powershell Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: powershell

I have a way of doing Arrays in other languagues like this:

```sh
$x = "David"
$arr = @()

$arr[$x]["TSHIRTS"]["SIZE"] = "M"
```

This generates an error.

Comment: As was pointed out earlier, the code that you have posted is a dictionary or a hash, not a common array.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You are trying to create an associative array (hash). Try out the following
sequence of commands

```sh
$arr=@{}
$arr["david"] = @{}
$arr["david"]["TSHIRTS"] = @{}    
$arr["david"]["TSHIRTS"]["SIZE"] ="M"
$arr.david.tshirts.size
```

Note the difference between hashes and arrays

```sh
$a = @{} # hash
$a = @() # array
```

Arrays can only have non-negative integers as indexes

Comment: Would this be an example of a 3D hashtable?

Comment: Note that negative indexes are meaningful in Powershell. `$arr[-1]` is the last item in the array, `$arr[-2]` is the next to last, and so on.

Answer (score 34):

from powershell.com:

PowerShell supports two types of multi-dimensional arrays: jagged arrays and true multidimensional arrays.

Jagged arrays are normal PowerShell arrays that store arrays as elements. This is very cost-effective storage because dimensions can be of different size:

```
$array1 = 1,2,(1,2,3),3
$array1[0]
$array1[1]
$array1[2]
$array1[2][0]
$array1[2][1]
```

True multi-dimensional arrays always resemble a square matrix. To create such an array, you will need to access .NET. The next line creates a two-dimensional array with 10 and 20 elements resembling a 10x20 matrix:

```
$array2 = New-Object 'object[,]' 10,20
$array2[4,8] = 'Hello'
$array2[9,16] = 'Test'
$array2
```

for a 3-dimensioanl array 10*20*10

```
$array3 = New-Object 'object[,,]' 10,20,10
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to access .NET:
[PS] C:\>$array = @(,@(,@(,@())))
[PS] C:\>$array[0][0][0] = 1

Comment: They aren't quite the same thing, anyway. One has to be referenced as $array[n,n], the other as $array[n][n].

Comment: With .NET it is also easier to pre-generate the dimension sizes. With the PS method mentioned above you would have to pre-generate it yourself or use the add operators to add new members. You can't simply write `$array[0]0][1] = 2` as that is out of bounds of the array. While `$array[1][0][0] = 2` would be indexing a null array. Which if you want a random access matrix that is not ideal.

Comment: the .net thing also adds coherence... if you define a Byte array... and you try to store some other type... Powershell will 'shout' to you!!! ;-)

Comment: For anyone who wants to use multidimensional arrays, you would use the [`GetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=net-5.0) method to get the number of elements for a specific dimension. For example, `$array2.GetLength(0)` would return 10 for `$array2 = New-Object 'object[,]' 10,20` and `$array2.GetLength(1)` would return 20.

Comment: @DaveF and `$array2.GetUpperBound(n)` to find the length in terms of its index number, which is what you need when looping over the array. It's equivalent to `$array.GetLength(n) - 1`. This method can incidentally also be used for normal PS arrays, where you simply enter a 0 for n, as it's one-dimensional.

Comment: In PS Core 7.x you can use a more concise syntax: `$array = [object[,]]::new(10, 20)`

Comment: @zett42 That's not new to  PowerShell 7, it works fine in PowerShell 5 as well.

Answer (score 17):

To extend on what manojlds said above is that you can nest Hashtables. It may not be a true multi-dimensional array but give you some ideas about how to structure the data. An example:

```
$hash = @{}

$computers | %{
    $hash.Add(($_.Name),(@{
        "Status" = ($_.Status)
        "Date"   = ($_.Date)
    }))
}
```

What's cool about this is that you can reference things like:

```
($hash."Name1").Status
```

Also, it is far faster than arrays for finding stuff. I use this to compare data rather than use matching in Arrays.

```
$hash.ContainsKey("Name1")
```

Answer (score 15):

Knowing that [PowerShell pipes objects between cmdlets](https://www.howtogeek.com/138121/geek-school-learning-powershell-objects/), it is more common in PowerShell to use an array of PSCustomObjects:

```
$arr = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'David';  Article = 'TShirt'; Size = 'M'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Eduard'; Article = 'Trouwsers'; Size = 'S'}
)
```

Or for older PowerShell Versions (PSv2):

```
$arr = @(
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = 'David';  Article = 'TShirt'; Size = 'M'}
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = 'Eduard'; Article = 'Trouwsers'; Size = 'S'}
)
```

And grep your selection like:

```
$arr | Where {$_.Name -eq 'David' -and $_.Article -eq 'TShirt'} | Select Size
```

Or in newer PowerShell (Core) versions:

```
$arr | Where Name -eq 'David' | Where Article -eq 'TShirt' | Select Size
```

Or (just get the size):

```
$arr.Where{$_.Name -eq 'David' -and $_.Article -eq 'TShirt'}.Size
```

---

<sup>Addendum 2020-07-13</sup>

### Syntax and readability

As mentioned in the comments, using an array of custom objects is straighter and saves typing, if you like to exhaust this further you might even use the [`ConvertForm-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) (or the [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)) cmdlet for building the array:

```
$arr = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Name,Article,Size
David,TShirt,M
Eduard,Trouwsers,S
'@
```

Or more readable:

```
$arr = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Name,   Article,   Size
David,  TShirt,    M
Eduard, Trouwsers, S
'@
```

<sub>**Note:** values that contain spaces or special characters need to be double quoted</sub>

Or use an external cmdlet like [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) which reads fixed width table formats:

```
$arr = ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
Name   Article   Size
David  TShirt    M
Eduard Trouwsers S
'
```

### Indexing

The *disadvantage* of using an array of custom objects is that it is slower than a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which uses a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).
Note that the *advantage* of using an array of custom objects is that can easily search for anything else e.g. everybody that wears a **TShirt** with size **M**:

```
$arr | Where Article -eq 'TShirt' | Where Size -eq 'M' | Select Name
```

To build an binary search index from the array of objects:

```
$h = @{}
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    If (!$h.ContainsKey($_.Name)) { $h[$_.Name] = @{} }
    If (!$h[$_.Name].ContainsKey($_.Article)) { $h[$_.Name][$_.Article] = @{} }
    $h[$_.Name][$_.Article] = $_ # Or: $h[$_.Name][$_.Article]['Size'] = $_.Size
}
```

```
$h.david.tshirt.size
M
```

**Note:** referencing a hash table key that doesn't exist in [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) will cause an error:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2
$h.John.tshirt.size
PropertyNotFoundException: The property 'John' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... Plain assoc array of objects - beautiful solution! :-)

Comment: `[PSObject]` works just as well. Less typing, more time for coffee.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple multidimensional array of strings.

```
$psarray = @(
 ('Line' ,'One' ),
 ('Line' ,'Two')
)

foreach($item in $psarray)
{
    $item[0]
    $item[1]
}
```

Output:

```
Line
One
Line
Two
```

Answer (score 5):

Another thread pointed here about how to add to a multidimensional array in Powershell. I don't know if there is some reason not to use this method, but it worked for my purposes.

```
$array = @()
$array += ,@( "1", "test1","a" )
$array += ,@( "2", "test2", "b" )
$array += ,@( "3", "test3", "c" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Two-dimensional arrays can be defined this way too as jagged array:

```
$array =  New-Object system.Array[][] 5,5
```

This has the nice feature that

```
$array[0]
```

outputs a one-dimensional array, containing `$array[0][0]` to `$array[0][4]`.
Depending on your situation you might prefer it over `$array = New-Object 'object[,]' 5,5`.
(I would have commented to CB above, but stackoverflow does not let me yet)

Answer (score 1):

you could also uses `System.Collections.ArrayList` to make a and array of arrays or whatever you want.
Here is an example:

```
$resultsArray= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
[void] $resultsArray.Add(@(@('$hello'),2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))
[void] $resultsArray.Add(@(@('$test', '$testagain'),3,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2))
[void] $resultsArray.Add("ERROR")
[void] $resultsArray.Add(@(@('$var', '$result'),5,1,1,0,1,1,0,2,3))
[void] $resultsArray.Add(@(@('$num', '$number'),3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2))
```

One problem, if you would call it a problem, you cannot set a limit. Also, you need to use `[void]` or the script will get mad.

Answer (score 1):

Using the .net syntax (like CB pointed above)
you also add coherence to your 'tabular' array...

if you define a  array...
and you try to store diferent types
Powershell will 'alert' you:

```
$a = New-Object 'byte[,]' 4,4
$a[0,0] = 111;    // OK
$a[0,1] = 1111;   // Error
```

Of course Powershell will 'help' you
in the obvious conversions:

```
$a = New-Object 'string[,]' 2,2
$a[0,0] = "1111";   // OK
$a[0,1] = 111;      // OK also
```

Answer (score 1):

Im found pretty cool solvation for making arrays in array.

```bsh
$GroupArray = @()
foreach ( $Array in $ArrayList ){
    $GroupArray += @($Array , $null)
}
$GroupArray = $GroupArray | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null}
```

Comment: This is pretty hard to follow. What's `$ArrayList` defined as? It seems pretty awkward to have to append nulls in there, then filter them out. What if the array has nulls in it?

Answer (score 0):

Lent from above:

```
$arr = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Name,Article,Size
David,TShirt,M
Eduard,Trouwsers,S
'@
```

Print the $arr:

```
$arr

Name   Article   Size
----   -------   ----
David  TShirt    M
Eduard Trouwsers S
```

Now select 'David'

```
$arr.Where({$_.Name -eq "david"})

Name  Article Size
----  ------- ----
David TShirt  M
```

Now if you want to know the Size of 'David'

```
$arr.Where({$_.Name -eq "david"}).size

M
```