# Writing a two-dimensional array to the Value2 property of an Excel range object in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new to PowerShell, and can't seem to figure out why the first method in the code below does not work, while the second method (commented out) does.
I'm trying to write the result of a database recordset to an Excel file, so i need a dynamically expandable array. I know how to do that with the first type of array, but not with the second type.
My problem would be solved if:

- you know how to dynamically expand the array of the second type
  Edit: As mentioned here http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2008/12/05/multidimensional-arrays.aspx this isn't possible.
- know how to write the array of the first type to the range
- Edit: or, you know an efficient method to convert the array of the first type to the second type.

The code:

```
#need this to work around bug if you have a non us-locale and English excel: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US" 

# This doesn't work
$values = @(('test1','test2'),('test3','test4'))

# This works
<#
$values = New-Object 'object[,]' 2,2
$values[0,0] = 'test1'
$values[0,1] = 'test2'
$values[1,0] = 'test3'
$values[1,1] = 'test4'
#>

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $False
$xls_workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$range = $xls_workbook.sheets.item(1).Range("A1:B2")
$range.Value2 = $values

$xls_workbook.SaveAs($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition.Replace($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name, "") + "test.xlsx")
$excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**Object[]**` is jagged array or array of arrays

`**Object[,]**` is 2 dimensional array.

Differences ["in nutshell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimensional-array)

And [How to convert jagged>2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291609/converting-jagged-array-to-2d-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

when I get the type for both variables:

```
$values1.GetType() 
$values2.GetType()
```

This is what I get:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                           
True     True     Object[,]                                System.Array
```

So $values1 is one-dimensional and $values2 is two-dimensional. There is a related question here:

[Powershell Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397137/powershell-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2008/12/05/multidimensional-arrays.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the post you mentioned led me to the link above, giving a part of the answer. The array of the second type can not be expanded once it's created.