# Automating Excel through PowerShell: $range.Value2 = $data only inserts zeroes

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm following the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937814/writing-a-two-dimensional-array-to-the-value2-property-of-an-excel-range-object) attempting to perform the same task, but whenever the script completes, the range is populated with zeroes instead of the actual data.

My data is in a two-dimensional PS array like so, of size [7,1]: [0, 1, 1, 82.26, 1.67, 1.93, 7.42]

The correct cells become filled, so I know the `$range = $workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$($rangeStart):$($rangeEnd)")` is working properly.

Why would it insert zeroes instead of the actual data? I'm going crazy!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I figured it out - my array was sideways, and due to it being one-dimensional only the first element of the array was inserted over and over, which happened to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - my array was sideways, and due to it being one-dimensional only the first element of the array was inserted over and over, which happened to be zero.

Instead of the array being of size [7,1], I should have made it size [1,7]