# Converting a Jagged Array to a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am converting a list within a list to an `int[][]` using:

```
int[][] preConvertInts = processedList.Select(array => array.ToArray().ToArray()) as int[][];
```

I am returning an `int[,]` in my method. What is the best way to convert an `int[][]` to an `int[,]`?

Edit: method

```
public static int[,] GetIntArrayInts(string dataString){
    string data = dataString;
    data = data.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");

    List<List<int>> processedList = new List<List<int>>();

    string[] rows = data.Split('\n');
    foreach (string row in rows){
        string[] columns = row.Split(',');
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();
        foreach (string column in columns){
            if (int.TryParse(column, out int tileGid)) ints.Add(tileGid);
        }
        processedList.Add(ints);
    }
    int[][] preConvertInts = processedList.Select(array => array.ToArray().ToArray()) as int[][];
    int[,] processedIntArray =  new int[preConvertInts[0].Length, preConvertInts[1].Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < preConvertInts.Length; i++){
        int[] intArray = preConvertInts[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < intArray.Length; j++){
            processedIntArray[i, j] = preConvertInts[i][j];
        }
    }
    return processedIntArray;
}
```

Comment: `int[][]` is Jagged array

Comment: I suppose best way would be to just use a for loop(s).

Comment: @mjwills I'm not sure what you're referring to since there is no problem I'm running into.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I was in the process of adding the method. There you go.

Comment: Thanks, deleted my comment.

Comment: Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26291720/4222487

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best way to convert an int[][] to an int[,]?

it is the one that is described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291609/converting-jagged-array-to-2d-array-c-sharp). Yours will actually also work if all sub-arrays have the same `Length`. But to cite you:

> Unfortunately, my array is not rectangular. – Luna

Then it would not make much sense to try to convert it. Unless you loose values or you add values to make the dimensions of all sub arrays equal.

But your problem in the code is not this conversion but **this one**:

> I am converting a list within a list to an `int[][]` using:
>   `int[][] preConvertInts = processedList.Select(array => array.ToArray().ToArray()) as int[][];`

This is wrong. You will get `null` for `preConvertInts`! if you check the return value of the `Select` call:

[image]

You can see that it returns `IEnumerable<int[]>` and not `int[][]`. Casting it with `as int[][];` does not work and masks only the fact that the 2 types are different from the compiler. What you do there is to convert each sublist into an array and then convert (the already converted array) simply again into an array.

You need to make the select in the proper way:

```
int [][] preConvertInts = processedList.Select(x=>x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Explanation:

1) in the first step you collect all sublists and convert each one into an array: `Select(x=>x.ToArray())`

2) now this call returns an `IEnumerable<int[]>` which you need to convert again to an array:

```
Select(x=>x.ToArray()).ToArray();
                     ^^
                     ||
    note the dot behind the closing parentesis of the Select call
```

Comment: Nice, up vote because im eating icecream and its awesome

Comment: @MichaelRandall Bon appétit

Comment: @MichaelRandall I added a freehand drawn circle and arrow to the image to make it even more awesome ;)

Comment: If i could vote up that arrow i would

Comment: This helped. I realised my mistake just a little later.

Comment: @Joris glad to hear that it helped. You might consider then to mark it as accepted :) happy coding

Comment: @Luna Hi, that is funny, you come back to this post after 5 months just to change your name in my answer. This post has still not any accepted answer. Did neither post here help you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Jagged Array**

```
public static T[,] ToMultiArray<T>(this IList<T[]> arrays)
{
    var length = arrays[0].Length;
    var result = new T[arrays.Count, length];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
    {
        var array = arrays[i];
        if (array.Length != length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Misaligned arrays");
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            result[i, j] = array[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Multidimensional Array**

```
public static T[][] ToJaggedArray<T>(this IList<T[]> arrays)
{

    var result = new T[arrays.Count][];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
    {
        var array = arrays[i];
        var length = array.Length;
        result[i] = new T[length];
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = array[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var preConvertInts = list.ToJaggedArray();
```

or

```
var preConvertInts = list.ToMultiArray();
```

## Update

> `this IList<T[]> arrays` this method is for lists which contain arrays,
>   to fit OP's example it should be (`this IList<List<T>> arrays`) – Mong
>   Zhu

**Jagged Array**

```
public static T[][] ToJaggedArray<T>(IList<List<T>> arrays)
{

    var result = new T[arrays.Count][];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
    {
        var array = arrays[i];
        var length = array.Count;
        result[i] = new T[length];
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = array[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Multidimensional Array**

```
public static T[,] ToMultiArray<T>(IList<List<T>> arrays)
{
    var length = arrays[0].Count;
    var result = new T[arrays.Count, length];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
    {
        var array = arrays[i];
        if (array.Count != length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Misaligned arrays");
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            result[i, j] = array[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

***Note*** : Totally untested

Comment: `this IList<T[]> arrays` this method is for lists which contain arrays, to fit OP's example it should be `(this IList<List<T>> arrays)`

Comment: @MongZhu thanks for the heads up

Comment: otherwise your method works. But so does the one in the duplicate :)

Comment: @MongZhu i have no idea!

Comment: @MongZhu thanks for the help :)

Comment: in `ToMultiArray` you could also check all sub arrays dimensions in the beginning : `if (arrays.Select(x => x.Count()).Distinct().Count() > 1)` and skip then the entire iteration if the dimension do not fit

Comment: These methods are useful. Unfortunately, my array is not rectangular.

Comment: @MongZhu also good point

Comment: @Joris the jagged array one will work for you

Comment: @Joris then it does not make sense for you to convert it into a multi dimensional array

Comment: `length` shouldn't be `arrays.Max(e => e.Count)`? Since a `List<T>` at index 0 could have less elements than the longest list inside of `arrays`.

Comment: @m.rogalski i guess in this example the multi version expects the same length, but you raise a good points, it could just creat the biggest occurrence and default up the type for anything missing