# How can I initialize an array of arrays (multidimensional) in PowerShell 5.0

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to partition out chunks of work using PowerShell (5.0) and am having a hard time instantiating a multidimensional array.

```
$n = 456;
$MaxChunks = 6;

$Chunks = @();

for($x = 0; $x -lt $MaxChunks; $x++)
{    
    Write-Host "Creating chunk $x"    
    $Chunks += @();
}
```

`$Chunks.Count` always returns 0 and I cannot access anything in $Chunks by index (i.e. `$Chunks[0]` is null).

Ultimately, my goal is to access the array located at `$Chunks[$i]` and add multiple `System.Data.DataRow` objects to it. However, as I've said, I'm not able to access the array at that index because that array is never instantiated.

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431840/powershell-add-to-multidimensional-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397137/powershell-multidimensional-arrays) but am not quite able to translate the hashtable scenario to my situation.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9397385/3905079) from your second link? That's the probably the information you need.

Comment: `$Chunks = ,@() * $MaxChunks`

Comment: @PetSerAl, it'll reuse the same object instance. Although it won't be a problem if the OP uses `+=` to populate those sub-arrays since `+=` recreates the array.

Comment: @wOxxOm Zero length arrays are effectively read-only, so (apart from reference equality) it does not matter if it reused or not.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955397/how-do-i-create-an-empty-array-of-arrays-in-powershell) may have an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively:

```
[System.Array] $chunks = [System.Array]::CreateInstance( [Int32], 3, 3 );

$chunks[0,0];
0
```

Not native PS, but works.

Answer (score 5):

- Replicate an empty array.
  The same object is referenced in each element but in this particular case it's not a problem because standard arrays are read-only and recreated when elements are added via `+=`.

  ```
  $Chunks = ,@() * $MaxChunks
  ```
- Collect foreach output:

  ```
  $Chunks = @(foreach ($x in 1..$MaxChunks) { ,@() })
  ```

  The outer @() handles a theoretically possible case when $MaxChunks = 1.
  You can use a more verbose (arguably slower) Write-Output -NoEnumerate:

  ```
  $Chunks = @(foreach ($x in 1..$MaxChunks) { echo -NoEnumerate @() })
  ```
- And in case the sub-arrays will be modified a lot, use ArrayList instead of `+=`:

  ```
  $Chunks = @(foreach ($x in 1..$MaxChunks) { ,[Collections.ArrayList]@() })
  ```

  and later:

  ```
  $Chunks[0].Add($something) >$null
  ```

P.S. Don't use `+=` to *generate entire arrays from scratch* regardless of its size as it's a terrible method that recreates and copies the entire array each time; there's a much faster and simpler output collection via loop statements such as foreach, for, while; there's ArrayList object for the case of frequent non-sequential modifications of an array.

Comment: BTW, why do you use `echo -NoEnumerate` instead of `,`?

Comment: Mainly because it's more verbose so less chance for a typo/overlook. Also, internally `,@()` creates two arrays, the outer one is unrolled (the overhead is negligible though so I guess I'll add it in the answer).

Comment: *Also, internally `,@()` creates two arrays* The same applies for `echo -NoEnumerate @()` too. And it also have overhead of instantiating `Write-Output` cmdlet, parameter binding, etc.

Comment: Sounds convincing.