# How do I create an empty array of arrays in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to create an empty array of arrays in Powershell to hold "tuples" of values (arrays are immutable).

Therefore I try something like:

The type of `$arr` is `Object[]`. I've read that `+= @(1,2)` appends the given element (i.e. `@(1,2)`) to `$arr` (actually creates a new array). However, in this case it seems that the arrays are concatenated, why?

```
$arr = @()
$arr += @(1,2)
$arr.Length // 2 (not 1)
```

If I do as follows, it seems that `$arr` contains the two arrays `@(1,2),@(3,4)`, which is what I want:

```
$arr = @()
$arr += @(1,2),@(3,4)
$arr.Length // 2
```

How do I initialize an empty array of arrays, such that I can add one subarray at a time, like `$arr += @(1,2)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer from Bruce Payette will work. The syntax seems a bit awkward to me, but it does work. At least it is not Perl.

Another way to do this would be with an `ArrayList`. To me, this syntax is more clear and more likely to be understood by another developer (or myself) in six months.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$al = @()

$al.Add(@(1,2))
$al.Add(@(3,4))

foreach ($e in $al) {
    $e
    $e.GetType()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The + operator concatenates arrays. To add an array as a single element, prefix the element to add with a comma. Something like `@() + , (1,2) + , (3, 4)`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you can't do it natively in PowerShell, nor can you do it with the `[System.Array]` type.  In both cases, you seem to need to define both the length and the type of the array.  Because I wanted a completely empty array of arrays, with the ability to store any type of value in the array, I did it this way.

```
$x=[System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$x.Count
$x.GetType()

$x.Add([System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()) > $null
$x.Count
$x[0].Count
$x[0].GetType()

$x[0].Add("first element") > $null
$x.Count
$x[0].Count
$x[0][0]
```