# Two-dimensional Array of Same Character

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I am experimenting on two-dimensional arrays. I want some sort of a matrix, all with the same character. I can define a blank multi-dimensional array with fixed elements, and supply it with a character using loops. However, I can also do `@(something)*n` to directly define an array already supplied with something.

From what I understood so far, this is how to do it:

```
> $arr = ,(,'E'*3)*3
```

These seems alright:

```
> $arr[1]
E
E
E
> $arr[1][2]
E
```

But when I try to replace a character somewhere, like `$arr[1][2] = 'D'`, many characters are replaced:

```
> $arr
E
E
D
E
E
D
E
E
D
```

Is my array definition wrong? *Added:* Then, how to correctly define it 'quickly'?

Comment: Your `$arr` contain same array three times, but not three separate arrays.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you know how to define the 'three separate arrays' thing 'quickly' like my (wrong) definition? Sorry for another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397137/powershell-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `*` operator on non-numeric values creates copies of the original value. However, if the item you're copying isn't of a primitive(-ish) type like String or Char, the result will not be a duplicate of that object, but a copy of the object *reference*. Since all instances will then be pointing to the same object, changing one will change all.

To create distinct instances you need to repeat the array instantiation in a loop, as PetSerAl showed in the comments:

```
$arr = 1..3 | ForEach-Object { ,(,'E' * 3) }
```

In this particular case you could also create a "template" array and clone it:

```
$a0 = ,'E' * 3
$arr = 1..3 | ForEach-Object { ,$a0.Clone() }
```

Note, however, that cloning an object will **not** clone nested object references, so the latter is not a viable approach in all scenarios.

Something like this won't work the way you intend (because the references of the *nested* hashtable objects are *still* pointing to the same actual hashtables after cloning the *array* object):

```
PS C:\> $a0 = ([PSCustomObject]@{'x'='E'}),([PSCustomObject]@{'x'='E'})
PS C:\> $arr = 1..2 | ForEach-Object { ,$a0.Clone() }
PS C:\> $arr

x
-
E
E
E
E

PS C:\> $arr[1][1].x = 'F'
PS C:\> $arr

x
-
E
F
E
F
```

But something like this will work:

```
PS C:\> $arr = 1..2 | ForEach-Object { ,(([PSCustomObject]@{'x'='E'}),([PSCustomObject]@{'x'='E'})) }
PS C:\> $arr

x
-
E
E
E
E

PS C:\> $arr[1][1].x = 'F'
PS C:\> $arr

x
-
E
E
E
F
```