# Powershell Array Issue when one item found

Tags: arrays, powershell, member-access-enumeration

I have created a script to automate some AD User account modification tasks.  The user is prompted to enter a partial last name which is used to look up any user account that matches the search criteria. I found my code has a mistake in my logic.  It works fine if it finds multiple matches - it will list each with the appropriate info, and it works ine if there are 0 matches - it returns a "User Not Found" message.  An issue only occurs if there is only 1 match found - in this case it returns an array of every letter of the users name and UserID.  I suspect it how I constructed my array but don't know for sure.  Any suggestions?

**One Match (Issue):strong text**
[image]

**Multiple Matches (Works Fine):**
[image]

**No Matches (Works Fine):**
[image]

**Where I suspect issue is:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
#prompt for last name (or at least portion of last name, then conver to a string with wild card for use in filter
$ticketNum = Read-Host "`nEnter the ServiceNow Ticket Number"
$lname = Read-Host "`nEnter at least the first three chars of users last name (you may enter full last name)"
$search = $lname + "*"

#Empty arrays
$ResultsArray=@("")
$ADUsersList=@("")

#add aduser properties to array, return error and exit if no user found
$ADUsersList += Get-ADUser -filter 'surname -like $search' -Properties * | select name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName,Enabled
if ($ADUsersList.count -le 1){
    Write-host "USER NOT FOUND"
    return
}

#populate a 2D array with NAM and with UserID
$ResultsArray = @(($ADUsersList.name),($ADUsersList.samaccountname),($ADUsersList.enabled))

Write-host "`t NAME `t`t`t USER ID `t`t ACCOUNT ENABLED"
#return list of found users and user ids. Preface with index number to use for selection menu
for($i=0;$i-le $ResultsArray[0].length-1;$i++){
    “[{0}] = {1} `t `t {2} `t `t {3}” -f $i,$ResultsArray[0][$i],$ResultsArray[1] [$i],$ResultsArray[2][$i] 
}

#Prompt 
$selection = (Read-Host "`nEnter number for user you want to modify") -as [uint32]

#Input validation - Only allow a valid index #.  If valid, write user selected to screen before proceeding 
if ($selection -notmatch '^[0-9]+$' -or $selection -gt $ResultsArray[0].length -or $selection -lt 0){
    Write-host "INVALID SELECTION!!!" -ForegroundColor Red
} 
else {
    Write-Host "`nYou selected user " -nonewline 
    Write-Host $ResultsArray[0][$selection] -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host " with user ID a of " -nonewline 
    Write-Host $ResultsArray[1][$selection] -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green
    $proceed = Read-Host "`nProceed with disabling for Leave Of Absence? (y or n)"
    if($proceed -eq "y"){
        Write-Host "proceeding ..."
        $target = $ResultsArray[1][$selection]
        $aduser = Get-ADUser -Identity $target -Properties *
        $prepend = "DISABLED per HR for LOA ($ticketNum) - "
        $desc = $aduser.description
        $loaDesc = $prepend + $desc
        Set-ADUser -Identity $target -description $loaDesc
        Disable-ADAccount -Identity $target
    }
    else{
        Write-host "no changes will be made"
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: or use `Out-GridView -PassThru` and avoid all trouble

Comment: Changing `@(($ADUsersList.name), (...))` to `@(@($ADUsersList.name), @(...))` would solve the problem, but a better solution is to just loop over `$ADUsersList` instead of constructing a nested array

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I like this GUI selector that Out-GridView -PassThru solution gives me.  Is there a way to enforce an end user to enter a minimum of 2 chars before it does the search on surname?  This way if they just hit the enter key it does not bring up the entire directory.

Comment: I don't know why this always makes my eye involuntarily twitch so much (it might just be because I'm old and grumpy :-) ), but ```$ResultsArray``` isn't a [2D array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_type)#Multi-dimensional_arrays) - it's a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)/. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397385/3156906 for more info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this statement right here:

```
#populate a 2D array with NAM and with UserID
$ResultsArray = @(($ADUsersList.name),($ADUsersList.samaccountname),($ADUsersList.enabled))
```

If `$ADUsersList` contains 1 object then `$ResultsArray` will no longer be a nested array - it'll be a flat array consisting of the three property values from that 1 user.

You can force the inner expressions to evaluate to arrays with the array subexpression operator `@(...)`:

```
$ResultsArray = @(@($ADUsersList.name), @($ADUsersList.samaccountname), @($ADUsersList.enabled))
```

... but a better way would be to forego the `$ResultsArray` step completely - you already have an array of objects with the relevant properties attached stored in `$ADUsersList`:

```
# ...

#add aduser properties to array, return error and exit if no user found
$ADUsersList = @(Get-ADUser -filter 'surname -like $search' -Properties * | select name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName,Enabled)

if ($ADUsersList.count -le 1){
    Write-host "USER NOT FOUND"
    return
}

# skip the `$ResultsArray` step completely

Write-host "`t NAME `t`t`t USER ID `t`t ACCOUNT ENABLED"
#return list of found users and user ids. Preface with index number to use for selection menu
for ($i = 0; $i -le $ADUsersList.Count; $i++) {
    "[{0}] = {1} `t `t {2} `t `t {3}" -f $i,$ADUserlist[$i].Name,$ADUserlist[$i].SAMAccountName,$ADUserlist[$i].Enabled
}
```

Comment: A minor improvement, if I may  `$Count=0;       $ADUsersList |  Foreach-Object {      "[{0}] = {1} `t `t {2} `t `t {3}" -f $Count++,$_.Name,$_.SAMAccountName,$_.Enabled }`

Comment: @sirtao Why would you introduce a separate counter variable? We're interested in the _index_ of the object - a piece of information already maintained by the `$i` variable assigned in the `for` loop declaration

Comment: As principle I try to avoid numbered `For` loops when looping through the entire amount of a collection. In my example `$Count`(though now I think about it might better renamed) serves the same function as `$i`. Plus, doesn't you example miss specifying the index? `$ADUserlist[$i].Name` instead of your `$ADUserlist.Name` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

To provide some **background information** to [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77874452/45375) (which is rightfully the accepted one):

Even though you've explicitly constructed `$ADUsersList` as an *array* (`@(...)`), extracting property values from the *elements* of the array via [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) (e.g. `$ADUsersList.Name`) is *not* guaranteed to return an *array* of property values, namely if the array happens to contain just *one* element.

That is, - perhaps surprisingly, see [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802) for a discussion - **member-access enumeration applies *pipeline-like logic* to the property values it retrieves**:

- a *single* value is output *as-is*
- *two or more* values are returned as a regular PowerShell *array*, i.e. of type `[object[]]`

Therefore, *if the array `$ADUsersList` happens to have only ONE element*:

- `$ADUsersList.Name` returns a single `[string]` instance rather than a (single-element) *array* of strings,
- Indexing into a `[string]` instance returns *characters* from that string; e.g., `'abc'[1]` is `b` - this is what you saw.

Therefore, in order **to ensure that a member-access enumeration returns an *array* of values**, you must either:

- either: wrap it in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), e.g. `@($ADUsersList.Name)`
- or, preferably, **cast it to `[array]`**, e.g. `[array] $ADUsersList.Name` - this is actually *more efficient*, because it doesn't involve enumeration and re-collection of the results in a *new* array if the result already *is* an array, which is what `@(...)` does.

A **self-contained, simplified example**:

```bash
# Create a single-element array.
$ADUsersList = @([pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'J.Doe' })

# Apply member-access enumeration:

# WITHOUT ensuring that that result is an array: 
#  `$ADUsersList.Name` is a single [string], 
#  and [0] extract its first *character*
# -> !! Outputs just 'J'.
$ADUsersList.Name[0]

# WITH ensuring that that result is an array.
#  `[array] $ADUsersList.Name` is a single-element array
#   and [0] extract its first *element*, i.e the contained [string].
# -> OK: 'J.Doe'
([array] $ADUsersList.Name)[0]
```